# Show OneDrive for business on a custom page

Tags: web-part

Users can access their OneDrive library by clicking the link next to 'Newsfeed' in the Suitebar. However, I would like to show this library in my main site collection. Is there a web part for this or do I have to write custom code to pull the library from MySites?

Answer (score 1):

The on-premise OneDrive sites are individual site collections for each user.  To expose a user's OneDrive libraries in a different site collection, you would need to write some custom code (maybe a web part).

You can get the link to their personal site from their user profile (so you can open the SPSite in your custom code).

Comment: Yes I agree, Onedrive is just a Document library ('Documents') part of the mySite site collection. I'll have to write a web part to access it from another site collection .thanks